# How to configure and start Azure Reserved Instance Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I have purchased 1 year termed Windows Virtual Machine, and money is taken from my card.

The resource is created successfully. Check the image below.

[image]

But when i want to start the machine, i don't see any Power On, or whatever button which says to start the virtual machine.

[image]

What am i missing here?

Comment: Did that help you?

Comment: sorry forgot to inform. yes I am clear now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you buy an Azure Reserved Virtual Machine Instance, the reservation discount is automatically applied to virtual machines that match the attributes and quantity of the reservation. A reservation covers the compute costs of your virtual machines.
You can deploy Virtual machines that matches the reservation attributes and the hardware portion of the VM will be covered.

Here is the document to [Manage reservations for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-manage-reserved-vm-instance)

After making an Azure Reserved VM Instance purchase, how do I know which VM got the Azure Reserved VM Instance discount?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-reserved-instance-usage